# What's the best way to test application API library in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, testing, rspec2

Im developing a ruby API library for some web application (not rails based). 
Library (in short overview) consists of the following objects:

- Client - main api class
- Request - module that handles all data transfers
- Item (record) - object with attributes (result of api operations)

Im having a hard time figuring out whats the best way to test such libraries?
Currently using RSpec2 and actual (live) requests. But also might use fixtures.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to mock requests. It has RSpec helpers to aid you in your tests.

I haven't personally used WebMock, but once used [Fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb) to accomplish a similar task. The only disadvantage of using mock requests is that if the remote code changes,